# How to View .cshtml Design Locally

Tags: c#, html, visual-studio, razor

I have a few .cshtml files which contains the design of a form in Visual Studio.

As I am debugging it locally, I do not have access to the database. Therefore, when I click on `View in Browser`, I will get errors.

May I know are there any others ways that can I preview the design of the form?

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio doesn't have a visual designer for razor pages like the one available for Web Forms. You could try opening the file with the "HTML (Web Forms) Editor" by using the option "Open with..." in that context menu, but I don't think it will render anything useful.

Your default option would be "View Markup", and you must interpret the layout of your form by looking at the HTML elements composing it.

Answer (score 0):

I have two possible suggestions:

1. Create a local database with the same basic schema and change the connection to it for debugging. This requires minimal changes to the existing code and is my preferred method.
2. Alternatively, create some dummy data to display on the page in place of what would be filled from the database. Probably a slightly quicker solution than the first one, but potentially means a lot of code edits.